# How to clear Maven 3 cache

Tags: android, maven, maven-3

I develop an Android application using Maven.

I removed several depdendencies from the `pom.xml` file, then ran `mvn clean install` and noticed that the removed dependencies are still used in dex invocation (`android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:dex`).

I deleted `.m2/cache` directory and put following code in my settings file as an attempt to fix this problem:

```
<settings>
    <profiles>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <enabled/>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy/>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled/>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy/>
          </snapshots>
          <id/>
          <name/>
          <url/>
          <layout/>
        </repository>
      </repositories>       
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

But it didn't help.

How can make Maven aware of the fact that the old dependencies (which I removed from the POM) should not be used in compilation of the application?

Comment: I suggest running `mvn dependency:tree` and making sure that the dependencies you expect to be removed aren't pulled by something else.

Comment: @alexwriteshere Thanks. Your suggestion actually helped me diagnose and fix the problem. Please add your text as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest running `mvn dependency:tree` and making sure that the dependencies you expect to be removed aren't pulled by something else.